# NSMutableString and (character)-encoding issue: getting \U00fc in case of ü

Tags: objective-c, ios, encoding, character-encoding, nsmutablestring

i am fetching my entity from coreData and saving the result of fetchrequest to an NSMutableString for text to speech.

```
self.ttsInboxCards = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];  
[self.ttsInboxCards appendString:[[entitySetsCards valueForKey:@"cardTitle"] description]];
```

And in NSLog i am getting this values:

```
F\U00fcr | schl\U00e4ge | zuh\U00f6ren
```

which should be:

```
Für | schläge | zuhören
```

I have tried a lot of things to get the correct encoding, for example with:

```
stringWithUTF8String:
```

and so on, but nothing worked.

**How can i prevent this issue?**

**EDIT 1:**

I am getting the values from coreData like this:
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntitySetsCardsInbox" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *inboxPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archived == 0 AND cardId != 0"];


[fetchRequest setPredicate:inboxPred];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:sortAsc selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor2, nil] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *cardTitles = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];



[self.ttsInboxCards appendString:[[cardTitles valueForKey:@"cardTitle"] description]];
```

**TextToSpeech**

```
    if (isSpeaking) {
    [vocalizer cancel];
    isSpeaking = NO;
}
else {
    isSpeaking = YES;
    vocalizer = [[SKVocalizer alloc] initWithLanguage:@"de_DE" delegate:self];
    [vocalizer speakString:tmp];


}
```

Comment: What is the type of the cardTitle property?  If it's a string, why are you invoking `-description` on it? You can just use the string itself.

Comment: it is string. if i remove the `description` then i am getting an **NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:**

Comment: Wait. `cardTitles` is an array. So, invoking `-valueForKey:` on it yields an array built by invoking `-valueForKey:@"cardTitle"` on each element. Then you're asking that array for its description. It's very likely to do formatting of its contents. What are you actually trying to achieve with that expression?

Comment: you drived me to the right direction. `componentsJoinedByString:` worked and solved the issue with encoding. now i have to split them correctly so that i can use it cleanly for text to speech. can you make an answer with that so i can mark this question as answered and others can find it faster. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote:

> cardTitles is an array. So, invoking -valueForKey: on it yields an
>   array built by invoking -valueForKey:@"cardTitle" on each element.
>   Then you're asking that array for its description. It's very likely to
>   do formatting of its contents.

brush51 wrote:

> componentsJoinedByString: worked and solved the issue with encoding.
>   now i have to split them correctly so that i can use it cleanly for
>   text to speech. can you make an answer with that so i can mark this
>   question as answered and others can find it faster

Answer (score 0):

Make that Caps `U` with smaller one and try.

Comment: i am not setting the caps by myself, i am getting them in console output.

Comment: Anyhow, you would have set those values somewhere, right? Change the values there and try.

Comment: I am getting this values from CoreData. in CoreData the text is correctly saved. I am saving: `Für | schläge | zuhören`. But in NSLog there are wrong. you got me? i have nothing to do with the **U**

Comment: Fine, got it. Will look at that.